# openalyers singleband pseudocolor

Tags: openlayers, geotiff

how to visualize geotiff with only value in band as pseudocolor for example from white to black (min: 0, max=1200)?

```
const source = new MultiGeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url:'image.tif',
    },
  ],
});


const layer =  new WebGLTile({
  source: source,
  style: pseudoColor,
})

const pseudoColor = ???
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a color ramp https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-math.html or palette https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/rendering/cases/webgl-palette/main.js

Comment: thanks Mike, color ramp works perfect!